# In R recover debugging, why do some functions display line-by-line debug output while others do not?

Tags: r, debugging

In R, I like to use the `error(mode=recover)` to browse the state of the interpreter when an error occurs. Today I've observed some behavior that I've never seen before. It seems for a particular function, it is treating my browser session in some kind of debug mode.

Here's what typically happens and what I expect. First, I call a function that results in an error, entering the `recover` mode:

```
library(projectInit)
options(error=recover)
projectInit("ews_patients")
Found config file: /home/x/code/ews_patients/metadata/project_config.yaml
Loaded config file: /home/x/code/ews_patients/metadata/project_config.yaml
  subprojects: rna,cellrep,bsdat
Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, pluralID, value = iPlural) : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: projectInit("ews_patients")
2: pepr::Project(cfgFile, subproject)
3: methods::new("Project", file = file, subproject = subproject)
4: initialize(value, ...)
5: initialize(value, ...)
6: .deriveAttributes(.Object)
7: .strformat(regex, as.list(samp), exclude, parentDir)
```

Now, if I choose anything from 1 to 3, I get the expected behavior. Here, I enter the browser, I can paste several lines of code in a for loop, and it just executes it in that environment. The output looks like this:

```
Selection: 1
Called from: initialize(value, ...)
Browse[1]> for (i in 1:2) {
+     message('hello1')
+     message('hello2')
+     message('hello3')
+ }
hello1
hello2
hello3
hello1
hello2
hello3
```

But now I exit this browser and choose `7` instead, paste the same dummy `for` loop, and I get this weird, line-by-line debug behavior:

```
Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: projectInit("ews_patients")
2: pepr::Project(cfgFile, subproject)
3: methods::new("Project", file = file, subproject = subproject)
4: initialize(value, ...)
5: initialize(value, ...)
6: .deriveAttributes(.Object)
7: .strformat(regex, as.list(samp), exclude, parentDir)

Selection: 7
Called from: eval(substitute(browser(skipCalls = skip), list(skip = 7 - which)), 
    envir = sys.frame(which))
Browse[2]> for (i in 1:2) {
+     message('hello1')
+     message('hello2')
+     message('hello3')
+ }
debug at #2: message("hello1")
Browse[5]> 
hello1
debug at #3: message("hello2")
Browse[5]> 
hello2
debug at #4: message("hello3")
Browse[5]> 
hello3
debug at #2: message("hello1")
Browse[5]> 
hello1
debug at #3: message("hello2")
Browse[5]> 
hello2
debug at #4: message("hello3")
Browse[5]> 
hello3
Browse[2]>
```

Here, the code being "debugged" is *what I am typing in to the recover browser*. I have to step through each line of code. This does *not* happen if I enter only 1 command, but *does* happen as soon as I enter multiple commands (*e.g.* `{ x=5; y=6 }`). I have never seen anything like  this before. It's not as if there's a function marked with `debug()`...this is not the function code executing, it's what I'm interactively typing into the browser. I get this debugging behavior when choosing any of 4, 5, 6, or 7 from the frame number selection prompt, but frames 1, 2, and 3 behave normally.

So my question is: First, what is going on here? Is this some kind of combination of `recover` and `debug`? Is this a documented R feature that starts some kind of line-by-line debugger within the recover browser? And second, *why* is this happening in one function but not any others? How is this behavior triggered or prevented? What I ultimately want to do is turn this off. I find it very annoying.

Comment: I have the same problem, mostly when I debug R6 classes. In RStudio, I call debug() or browser() and I open the function to be debugged. At one point, all the calls in the function are opened in a new debugging session. I did not find a solution yet and I am not sure when this behaviour is triggered either.